# How to use private channel in Laravel Pusher.js

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-9, pusher-js

I use Pusher.js in Laravel.

Here is a private channel:

```
    return new PrivateChannel('user.'.$this->user->id);
```

With permissions:

```
Broadcast::channel('user.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    return true;
  });
```

The `PrivateChannel` has channel prefix name in constructor:

```
parent::__construct('private-'.$name);
```

Therefore I use `private-` prefix in JS client:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-user.1');
channel.bind('PrivateEvent', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The problem is I got client error, because the private channel awaits auntification:

```
Pusher :  : ["Error: Unable to retrieve auth string from channel-authorization endpoint - received status: 404 from /pusher/auth. Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels.
```

Why should I use auntification twice if Laravel already checks this in route channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to **authorize** your request by adding the `authEndpoint` and add the `jwt_token` like this after that you could listen to the **channel**

```
var pusher = new Pusher("PUBLIC_KEY", {
  cluster: 'eu',
  authEndpoint: `https://domain_name.com/broadcasting/auth`,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_JWT_TOKEN",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  }
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-user.1');
channel.bind('PrivateEvent', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I use laravel api as backend what url should I wrtie for authEndpoint? and should I set a route for that?

Comment: No, it is set by default when you use sanctum

Answer (score 0):

The API has been updated in 8, now you will want to provide a channelAuthorization like so:

```
var pusher = new Pusher("PUBLIC_KEY", {
  cluster: 'eu',
  channelAuthorization: {
    endpoint: `https://domain_name.com/broadcasting/auth`,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_JWT_TOKEN",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  }
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-user.1');
channel.bind('PrivateEvent', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```